# Find the settings JNDI is using for error reporting

Tags: java, jndi

I've got a J2SE application that I am maintaining uses JNDI.
(It uses JNDI to find it's J2EE application server.)

It has pretty poor error reporting of failure to find the JNDI server.

I've been looking around fora way to display which server the InitialContext is trying to talk to.

Has anyone got a neat way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting the value for `InitialContext.getEnvironment().get(Context.PROVIDER_URL)` might be helpful.

Comment: Slight caution in using an initial  context thet mey be null,
but otherwise great. Thanks.